# Cant select * from table

Tags: php, sql

I wrote a code for selecting all from table, but have no response. Same code works for all other tables.

```
require_once 'connect.php';

$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM city");

if($query)
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $flag[]=$row;
    }
print(json_encode($flag));
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

[image: table image]

I tested this code and I don't get any result.. for all other tables in my db this code works perfectly

Comment: Getting no row? or getting error message?

Comment: @mkRabbani  getting no row..

Comment: Did you check your table really has records? or connecting to the appropriate database or table or not?

Comment: `$flag = array();` initiate at top level outside the loop

Comment: table has 16 records.. and is in the same db as all other tables I'm usiong.. so connection is the same

Comment: what r u getting blank page? use ELSE if query not return true... and use mysqli_error

Comment: @devpro but i use the exact same code for other tables, and works perfectly...  yes blank page.. i added some echo under if condition.. and echo was returned.. so connection is ok

Comment: `if($query)
{// your code}else{// print mysqli_error();}` and share the result

Comment: @devpro  i added some echo under if condition.. and echo was returned.. so connection is ok... is it possible that i have to edit some options in database?

Comment: then u must need to check what r u getting in`$flag` by using `print_r($flag);` before this line `print(json_encode($flag));
`

Comment: What is inside your `connect.php`?

Comment: @devpro print_r($flag); is returning all of the cities in table

Comment: `echo json_encode($flag,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`; try like that

Comment: @devpro I found the problem.. so the problem is that some cities in the table have Croatian letters like č,ć,ž,š,đ.. how can I overcome this problem without eliminating theese letters?

Comment: Since you say that the same exact query works on MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721445/php-mysqli-returns-no-rows-while-manual-sql-query-returns-results

Comment: @DinoKrivičić your table have Croatian letters like č,ć,ž,š,đ..

Comment: What is the output of `mysqli_error()`?

Answer (score 2):

To read `UTF-8 character` correctly from the database to webpage, you can create your table like this:-

```
create table demo(
/* your columns  */
)character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[image]

and also, remember to set your `html charset to UTF-8`:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and to **insert/retrieve** your data by adding **set_charset('utf8')** in php:

```
   $mysqli=new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Could not connect to database. Error: '.mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }


$query="select * from YOURTABLE";
$result=$mysqli->query($query);

if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        //reading $row data
    }
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```